# How can I find where WordPress is located?

Tags: directory, filemanager, wordpress

How can I find where WordPress is located on Ubuntu?  I have installed it using the instructions provided by the official Ubuntu tutorial: [Install and configure WordPress](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#1-overview)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you search for WordPress data directory. Try this easy search:

```
sudo find / -iname "wordpr*"
```

**Little bit more exact procedure is here:**

List web services to find config file of the web pages.

```
service --status-all | grep -e "apache" -e "nginx" -e "http"

# eventually do full list of services:
service --status-all
```

Here is an example of the output. The **Nginx** web service is running in my case. See `+` sign:

```
 [ - ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ - ]  apache2
 [ + ]  nginx
```

List all virtual webs and search for possible WordPress config file.

```
# Nginx:
ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

# Apache:
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

If only one file is listed, it is a Wordpress web configuration file. Search for name like `wp` or `wordpreess`  if more files are found. Let the file be named e.g. `wordpress`.

Now review this `wordpress` file with potential WordPress setting. Search for data directory path in the file.

```
# Nginx example:
grep "root" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress

# Apache example:
grep -i "\<Directory " /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress
```

Example of output:

Nginx:

```
root /var/www/wordpress;
# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
root /var/www/wordpress;
```

Apache:

```
<Directory />
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
```

Your WordPress directory is `/var/www/wordpress` in both cases.

Note:

Sometimes only web config file is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` if no virtual webs are set.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is `whereis wordpress`

Comment: While the original question is unclear, it's more likely that the OP wants to know where the WordPress *data* is (see the other answer) rather than the *binary*. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The provided tutorial installs it to `/srv/www/wordpress/`.